# UIModalTransitionStyle horizontal movement

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, animation, modalviewcontroller

The UIModalTransitionStyle is either Vertical, Flip or Dissolve. I would like it to be right to left or left to right, like if you click on a disclosure button on a MapKit callout or in a navigation based app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is impossible as transition for a modal viewController, but you could use a CATransition with a type of `kCATransitionMoveIn` or `kCATransitionPush` and a subtype of `kCATransitionFromRight`

```
CATransition* trans = [CATransition animation];
trans.type = kCATransitionPush;
trans.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
trans.duration = 0.5;

[newView.layer addAnimation:trans forKey:@"PushFromRightEffect"];

[someOtherView addSubview:newView];
// Coded in Browser not tested
```

Comment: Right now "someOtherView" just disappears during the transition to "newView". I want "someOtherView" to still be visible beneath the "newView" throughout the whole animation. Is this possible?