# iOS Horizontal transition of UIView controller

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, uiviewcontroller

Hi I have a problem I want to do horizontal transition but in other forum they say it is impossible

```
CrossViewController *screen = [[CrossViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;//here i must add som horizontal transition animation
        [self presentModalViewController:screen animated:YES];
        [screen.but setTitle:@"funguje" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        //screen.vyberUcet;
        [screen release];
```

I found that but it does not work

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509869/uimodaltransitionstyle-horizontal-movement)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [UIViewController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) the only valid UIModalTransitionStyle transitions supported by the presentModalViewController method are currently (iOS 4.2):

- UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical
- UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal
- UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve
- UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl

(See the "UIModalTransitionStyle" information within the "Constants" section towards the end of the document.)

Are you sure you want to present the view modally? (I can't help but wonder if you're attempting to create a [UINavigationController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) style set up.)

Comment: You suggestion to use UINavigationController made me reassess my storyboard and decide to move the Navigation embedding earlier. Good call.

Answer (score 2):

If you set this up inside a UINavigationController, set `navigationBarHidden` to `YES`, and then do the usual UINavigationController pushing and popping functions, does that get you what you want?

If not, then I don't know what you mean by "horizontal transition".

Comment: I was not working whit nav controller but I start to implement it to my project.The truth is I m just getting familliar with x code and objective C.It takes a little time for me, but thanks a lot for all the help Guys

Answer (score 1):

```
screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
```

is not exactly what i looking for but it is enough for now thanks for help.