# iOS How to make more slow animation for api presentviewcontroller and dissmissviewcontroller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewanimation

I am using following code to slow animation.

```
      vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;
      vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;

      [self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];
```

for dismiss view used

```
 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

I need animation from Bottom to Top for presentviewcontroller and Top to bottom for dismissviewcontroller.

But this animation also to fast.How to make it slow?

Comment: transition.duration = 1; or more and try once

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699891/present-modal-view-with-animation-effect

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik. I referred that link animation is fine but it is not presenting view controller. it adding subview. Could you suggest other solution?

Comment: sure , just wait ....

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik. hey could you help me to fix this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40149922/ios-setting-and-accessing-value-in-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set duration time is more than 3...

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 3.4;
transition.type = kCATransitionMoveIn;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop;
[[[[self  view] window] layer] addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];

[self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:NULL];
```

**In Swift :-**

```
let transition: CATransition = CATransition()
transition.duration = 3.4
transition.type = kCATransitionMoveIn
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop
self.view.window?.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)

self.present(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Comment: where can I find that `transition` variable?

Comment: @gerbil you need to create this transition variable and add it to your desired view's layer property as animation.